# using SQL Server NTILE function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am using CTE to select a set of records. As you can see from the code below, I am assigning a point based on the student's grade. Using this CTE, I need to insert a set of records into the SourceStudentRiskFactor table that satisfy the following criteria. Group by fst.ClassKey; for each group, select records where Sum(Points) is in the 3rd quartile (for ntile(4). Any examples would be highly appreciated.

```
with AtRiskBarExam as (
    select
        fr.PersonalIdentifier,
        fr.StudentLevelKey,
        dimGrade.SourceKey,
        case 
            when dimGrade.SourceKey = 'A' then 2
            when dimGrade.SourceKey = 'B' then 1
            when dimGrade.SourceKey = 'C' then 0.5
            else 0
        end AS Points
    from
        Final.FactRegistration fr
        inner join  Final.DimTerm dimTerm
            on  dimTerm.TermKey = fr.TermKey and
                fr.VersionKey = 1
        inner join  Final.DimGrade dimGrade
            on  dimGrade.GradeKey = fr.GradeKey 
        inner join Final.DimStudentLevel dimStudentLevel
            on dimStudentLevel.StudentLevelKey = fr.StudentLevelKey and
            dimStudentLevel.SourceKey = 'GR'
    group by
        fr.PersonalIdentifier,
        fr.StudentLevelKey,
        dimGrade.SourceKey
)

insert into Stage.SourceStudentRiskFactor(
        PersonalIdentifier,
        StudentLevelCode,
        StudentTermCode,
        RiskFactorCode)
    select
        fst.PersonalIdentifier,
        fst.StudentLevelCode,
        fst.StudentTermCode,
        'AtRiskBarExam'
    from
        Final.FactStudentTerm fst
        inner join  Final.DimTerm dimTerm
            on  dimTerm.TermKey = fst.TermKey and
                dimTerm.IncludeTermInLoad = 1 and
                fst.VersionKey = 1
        inner join  AtRiskBarExam e
            on  fst.PersonalIdentifier = e.PersonalIdentifier and
                fst.StudentLevelKey = e.StudentLevelKey
        inner join final.DimClass dimClass
            on dimClass.ClassKey = fst.ClassKey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the sample data to make it a little easier for me to follow. Don't worry, it should still work on your CTE since I didn't change the column names.

```
WITH YourCte
AS
(
    SELECT  'Student1' AS PersonalIdentifier, 7 as TotalPoints, 'Class1' as MaxClassKey
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student2',1,'Class1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student3',3,'Class1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student4',6,'Class1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student5',3,'Class1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student6',4,'Class1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student7',9,'Class1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student8',1,'Class1'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student9',1,'Class2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student10',3,'Class2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student11',6,'Class2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student12',3,'Class2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student13',4,'Class2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student14',9,'Class2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student15',1,'Class2'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Student16',1,'Class2'
)

SELECT  *,
        --Partition causes NTILE() to look at the classes as individual groups
        NTILE(4) OVER (PARTITION BY MaxClassKey ORDER BY TotalPoints) ClassQuartile
FROM YourCte
```

Results:

```
PersonalIdentifier TotalPoints MaxClassKey ClassQuartile
------------------ ----------- ----------- --------------------
Student2           1           Class1      1
Student8           1           Class1      1
Student5           3           Class1      2
Student3           3           Class1      2
Student6           4           Class1      3
Student4           6           Class1      3
Student1           7           Class1      4
Student7           9           Class1      4
Student9           1           Class2      1
Student15          1           Class2      1
Student16          1           Class2      2
Student12          3           Class2      2
Student10          3           Class2      3
Student13          4           Class2      3
Student11          6           Class2      4
Student14          9           Class2      4
```